# emmake make command makes error when used for openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to make a simple application in cpp that uses openCV and compile it to wasm. I followed the documentation and tried to produce static library files *.a and the cpp file that references the opencv library as a .o file. This is where I had the error.
I ran the command

- cmake ../ -B./ -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DWITH_1394=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF
  to build opencv statically into the current folder. Then I ran the commands
- make
- sudo make install

after this I navigated to where my cpp file is, then ran

- cmake .
- make

based on this I get the executable. It all works well here.
But when I ran the following commands instead based on the documentation, I got the error.

- emcmake cmake ../ -B./ -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DWITH_1394=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF
- emmake make

error happens.

make: make
Scanning dependencies of target gen-pkgconfig
[  0%] Generate opencv.pc
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
Scanning dependencies of target ittnotify
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/ittnotify/CMakeFiles/ittnotify.dir/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_static.c.o
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/3rdparty/ittnotify/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_static.c:59:
/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/3rdparty/ittnotify/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_config.h:376:12: error: implicit declaration of function '**TBB_machine_fetchadd4' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
return **TBB_machine_fetchadd4(ptr, 1) + 1L;
^
1 error generated.
emcc: error: '/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -D__EMSCRIPTEN_PTHREADS**=1 -DEMSCRIPTEN -fignore-exceptions -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major**=2 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=0 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=17 -D_LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION=2 -Dunix -D__unix -D__unix__ -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/SDL --sysroot=/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/compat -I/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/3rdparty/ittnotify/include -I/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/WasmBuild/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv/include -I/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/WasmBuild/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw/include -I/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/WasmBuild -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-undef -Wno-sign-compare -O3 -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -fPIC -c -pthread /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/3rdparty/ittnotify/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_static.c -o CMakeFiles/ittnotify.dir/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_static.c.o' failed (1)
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/ittnotify/CMakeFiles/ittnotify.dir/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_static.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/ittnotify/CMakeFiles/ittnotify.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
emmake: error: 'make' failed (2)

From what I understand the ittnotify is causing error. But somehow it was fine when I did the normal cmake and make. It only does this for emcmake cmake and emmake make.

/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/work/new/emscripten_playground/opencv-3.4.14/3rdparty/ittnotify/src/ittnotify/ittnotify_config.h:376:12: error: implicit declaration of function '__TBB_machine_fetchadd4' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
return __TBB_machine_fetchadd4(ptr, 1) + 1L;
^
1 error generated.

Please help.

Comment: I think that's rather a topic for a bug report than a question here. In order to prepare for asking here, you'd have to extract a [mcve] from the code you're trying to compile, which is probably not what you want. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Emscripten is little more strict that other compiler WRT to implicit function declarations.

See https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/4e35687f2dca1171eca0735820d4f7f5ac65f363/emcc.py#L837-L842

You can pass `-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration` to the compiler to override this, as long as you are aware that it can lead to potential signature mismatches later down the line.

Ideally you would instead fix the upstream code to avoid the implicit declarations.. but that isn't always an option.